# Selector Syntax in Puppeteer

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to create a script that in part functions press buttons on a webpage using Puppeteer. I keep getting a "not a valid selector " error or a variable remaining undefined after trying to execute the line shown below shown below.

```
var termselector = await page.$$( ":button" );
//yields "not a valid selector"
```

or

```
var termselector = await page.$$( "#zci-images > div.detail.detail--slider.detail--images.detail--xd > div > div.detail__panes.js-detail-panes > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.detail__body.detail__body--images > div > div > a" );
//yields "termselector undefined"
```

Perhaps I am just fundamentally misunderstanding how selectors work, but I've looked through some JQuery documentation, and I still can't seem to properly format my selectors. Where can I find rules for proper selector syntax for use in puppeteer? Please excuse my ignorance

Answer (score 3):

With the line:

```
await page.$$( );
```

you have to use [css](/questions/tagged/css) selectors: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Or you can use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query too: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

```
await page.$x( );
```

If you know well JQuery, maybe give a try to [cheerio](/questions/tagged/cheerio):

https://tshaped.io/javascript-scraping-for-marketers-cheerio-and-puppeteer/
https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

---

CSS selector example for the first picture on [your provided link](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bruh&t=hk&iax=images&ia=images):

```
$$('#zero_click_wrapper img[src^="//external-content"]')[0]
```

It means:

- start matching *HTML nodes* with ID: `zero_click_wrapper`
- ...followed by an image `img` that the `src` tag starts with `//external-content`

Comment: Allow me to be more specific. If you went to this link (the one I'm working with in the script): https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bruh&t=hk&iax=images&ia=images         ,   you could view the selector:```"#zci-images > div.detail.detail--slider.detail--images.detail--xd > div > div.detail__panes.js-detail-panes > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.detail__body.detail__body--images > div > div > a"``` and if you right clicked the element and copied its path, you would get that selector. How do i format it into a useable selector?

Comment: It's a no match. `$$("#zci-images > div.detail.detail--slider.detail--images.detail--xd > div > div.detail__panes.js-detail-panes > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.detail__body.detail__body--images > div > div > a")[0]`

Comment: What do you want to retrieve ? An image ?

Comment: Added example in my post

Comment: Yes, or any kind of file. I'm really trying to just understand proper selector syntax for this language. I seem to be missing something in my understanding of CSS selectors. Thanks for the example. Where can i find documentation on that format you're using specifically? Also: ```var termselector = await page.$$('#zero_click_wrapper img[src^="//external-content"]')[0];``` yielded a " termselector is not defined"

Comment: I provided a link that explains CSS selectors

Comment: thanks, I see that. As I said, using the example selector yielded an undefined error. This suggests that it is not valid.

Comment: Just following up to if you had come up with a functioning selector yet